# Inherit CSS in Vue components

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have two components that they have a childs in router like this:

```
{
        path: '/admin',
        component: AdminMain,
        children:[
            {
                path: '/admin',
                component: AdminHome,
                name: 'AdminHome'
            }
        ]
 },
 {
        path: '/',
        component: Home,
        children:[
            {
                path: '/',
                component: Index,
                name: 'Index'
            }
        ]
 }
```

I want to do two separate layout for these components so their childs inherit parents css. It is possible ?  At the moment I load css file in every component with scoped because my css file conflict with vuetify css.

Comment: I had an answer for a similar question in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49654061/5599288 . Maybe it will be useful to you.

Comment: @JacobGoh Unfortunately in my case it not working. Imported code in SCSS is out of te selector body as new <style> tag

Answer (score 2):

> DOM content created with v-html are not affected by scoped styles, but you can still style them using deep selectors.

This wording in the [Deep Selectors](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) page of the Vue docs sounds like it contradicts itself. But it's saying, for instance, if you want to scope-style a 'p' element and have those changes show up in a v-html, your css should look like this.

```css
>>> p {
/* some css */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you [deep selectors](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) to affect css of child component

**AdminMain.vue** (parent component)

```
<style scoped>
.a >>> .b { /* ... */ }
</style>
```

will be translate to `.a[data-v-f3f3eg9] .b { /* ... */ }`

then .b will effect children component (AdminHome.vue)

Comment: Ok, but i use bootstrap. In this case i must add ">>>" operator in the whole file?

Comment: With 3rd party css, you can import it in `main.js` or `root` component.