# Vuetify css crushes Bootstrap css

Tags: css, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify in my Vue components. I want to use vuetify css in the components I use Vuetify.

i'm adding this code `import VuetifyCss from 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'` to my local component but it affects all project so it crushes bootstrap's some css.

How can i import vuetify.min.css into my local component which i used ?

Answer (score 3):

This [person](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54677116/11237455) used the scoped attribute:

```
 <style scoped src="vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css"></style>
```

in the Component you want to use Vuetify in. Seemed to work for them judging by their answer.

Comment: Sounds like scoped would be removed, chrome and firefox didn't implemented it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28633425/6805420