# Import scoped css

Tags: vue.js

Why do I import scoped but it still affects other components.I have consulted this article but the solutions are generating error [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49653931/scope-bootstrap-css-in-vue]. Thanks.

```
<style scoped>
    @import '/public/admin/bs3/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    @import '/public/admin/css/bootstrap-reset.css';
    @import '/public/admin/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
    @import '/public/admin/css/style.css';
    @import '/public/admin/css/style-responsive.css';
</style>
```

Comment: `/public/admin/bs3/css/bootstrap.min.css` these look like relative URLS and they shouldn't be. They should be relative paths to local files. Like in your `node_modules` directory.

Comment: So the issue is, the imported CSS files are not scoped as expected? If that's the case. IIRC importing already compiled CSS files like that don't give scoped CSS.

Comment: @Kunukn Hi Did you find the solution for this? Because I am also facing the same issue in Vuejs/Nuxtjs and tried many things but nothing seems to work for me.